# RPI4 8gb Ubuntu 18 won't boot, requires updated kernel, when will this be available?

Tags: 18.04, drivers, kernel, raspberrypi

Is there a time line for a kernel update to allow the 18.04 LTS image - https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi to work on the newest pi 4 8gb?

Looking around on the internet - https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=276057 it seems to be a problem with modified power supply circuitry, requiring a modified driver. I literally bought a new pi 4 because i can't get into work (COVID 19) to get one of my many pi 4's, and it seemed stupid not to get the one with the most RAM.

The Ubuntu 20 image will boot fine, but there's pretty much no support for anything ROS related. Noetic is and Ubuntu 20 are way to bleeding edge, realsense drivers won't work, along with a lot of other things, plus i don't think the messages are compatible with Melodic the same way kinetic and melodic messages are compatible, so i would have to upgrade my entire eco system if i could actually install stuff, which i can't.

There are a whole bunch of issues around installing ros on Raspberry pi OS, and again, Realsense drivers don't work properly, so this is not an option either.

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

A workaround -

https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-4-ubuntu-server-desktop-18-04-3-image-unofficial/

James Chambers did some fine work before Ubuntu 18 was officially supported on the pi 4, his version, last updated 25th of February boots fine. Looking at the github page - https://github.com/TheRemote/Ubuntu-Server-raspi4-unofficial/releases He seems to have ironed out the vast majority of all the bugs.